# PHP session expiring quickly and randomly

Tags: php, session, session-variables

My PHP sessions are expiring randomly and rarely last more than approximately 5 mins (300 secs).

I am experimenting with the PHP & MySQL login script here: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL (sec_session_start function extracted below).

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}
```

I have done extensive reading into the subject to try and solve the problem and understand that many reasons cause PHP sessions to expire prematurely.  If you have any ideas about how I could solve the problem please let me know as the problem's driving me mad!

Please note:
1. In php.ini I have set session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
2. My host is IPage.
2. I have tried editing session_set_cookie_params to the following, but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
    session_set_cookie_params( time()+1800, "/", $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
```

Comment: have you check if the server + client clocks are relatively in-sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar login script, and found the solution when I looked at the cookies I was setting.  For some reason this script will set cookies for both example.com and www.example.com when a brand new session is started.  Explicitly setting your domain in session_set_cookie_params() will fix this behavior.

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $domain = 'example.com'; // note $domain
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = true; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $domain, $secure, $httponly); // note $domain
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a single, unchanging name for every single session? Have you considered that every time someone starts a new session it will clobber the previous one? There is a reason why session identifiers are unique.

Aside from that, ask your host. They might be doing something ridiculous like clearing /tmp every X minutes.

Answer (score 0):

it might be same issue as described here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#84242

it is browser issue, not php. (Way easier to recreate in Firefox than Chrome)
Setting "session_regenerate_id(false);" helps, but that defeats the purpose of secure login.